# Python PIP causes error

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, pip

Hey guys i've got a problem with installing PyOpenGL via pip. It says that, there's an error during running some setup.py... but idk what that means... I have tried to install pyinstaller as well... but the same issue occurs. I'm using python 3.6.3... It worked on 3.5, but then either cx_freeze or pyinstaller doesn't work at all...

It only happens everytime when pip has to use some setup.py
[image: The Photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution... In  **`Python36-32\Scripts`** directory I opened console and passed into it the following command:

**`easy_install pyopengl`**

And this hopefully worked. I'll leave this post in case if somebody else would have the same problem.

Happy coding!